# How can i retrieve the username form the keycloak user?

Tags: java, keycloak, quarkus

I'm running a quarkus setup with keycloak. To start of I am trying to implement the [tutorial](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-keycloak-authorization) into my code. I have to note here that i didn't copy the realm that is used. The reason for this is that we received a realm from our tutors.

This is the code I am trying to implement. The problem with is that it doesn't return the user.

```java
@Path("/api/users")
public class UserResource {
    @Inject
    SecurityIdentity identity;

    @GET
    @Path("/me")
    @NoCache
    public User me() {
        return new User(identity);
    }

    public static class User {
        private final String userName;

        User(SecurityIdentity identity) {
            this.userName = identity.getPrincipal().getName();
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }
    }
}
```

When I enabled policy enforcer, I wasn't even able to login, all request became 403 or 401.

```
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true
```

How can we solve this issue?

Another question would be if it is possible to retrieve some sort of userId from keycloak?

Comment: Hi, I've tested https://github.com/sberyozkin/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/security-keycloak-authorization-quickstart, and I can see with `curl` that a user name is returned. Please make sure Keycloak is configured to return a username - I did not have to use any specific configuration though. Re the policy enforcer - not sure why you are seeing it as the quickstart this tutorial is based upon works - please don't forget to import a keycloak realm

Comment: The problem is that I need to use a specific realm, so I can't use the one of the tutorial. I am more looking at what kind of settings I need to change within keycloak to get the ID or the username.

Comment: I see, perhaps the simplest way forward is to import the demo realm, check how a user such as `alice` is configured compared to how users are configured in your realm and align as needed. FYI, Keycloak typically uses `preferred_username` claim to pass the user name in the token so check in the demo realm if `preferred_username` is explicitly allowed etc. And likewise, as far as the policy enforcement is concerned - note you should only use the policy enforcer if you intend to use Keycloak to have authorization decisions as opposed to the local RBAC